# How to traverse a nested list from deepest elements

Tags: python

Im programming a system of statistical querys in python.  The inputs of the users must be like this:

```
["Comand",parameter1, parameter2,.... ,parametern]
```

My code reads the first element an looks if there is a function with that name. Then takes the parameters and executes.

The problem is that the user can enter a query with this structure

```
["Cmd1",["cmd2",p1, p2..., pn], x2,...,xn]
```

So i need to execute the cmd2 first an then use what it returns to execute cmd1. The nesting is arbitrary.

Thanks for the help

Comment: can you provide an example of how you 'execute' a command from a list?

Comment: Loop over the parameters and if one happens to be a list, then (recursively) process its elements.

Comment: Why not use a nested dictionary structure for this, as a design suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Foo( a, b, c ):
    print( "Foo(%r, %r, %r)" % ( a, b, c ) )
    return 23456

def Bar( a, b ):
    print( "Bar(%r, %r)" % ( a, b ) )
    return 12345

LEGAL_COMMANDS = dict(   # map the names by which users will refer to commands, to the names you have given to the corresponding implementations in your code
    Foo=Foo,
    Bar=Bar,
)

def ExecList( lst ):
    cmd = lst[ 0 ]
    if cmd in LEGAL_COMMANDS:
        cmd = LEGAL_COMMANDS[ cmd ]
    else:
        raise ValueError( "%r is not a recognized command" % cmd )
    params = [ ( ExecList( param ) if param and isinstance( param, list ) else param ) for param in lst[ 1: ] ]
    return cmd( *params )
```

Test call, with output:

```
>>> answer = ExecList( [ "Foo", 10, (20,30), ["Bar", 40, "baz" ] ] )
Bar(40, 'baz')
Foo(10, (20, 30), 12345)
>>> answer
23456
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_args(user_input):
    args = []
    command = user_input[0]
    for item in user_input[1]:
        if type(item) == list:
            args.append(process_args(item))
        else:
            args.append(item)
    return run_command(command, args)
```

Comment: This will throw an error if `item` is not a list because you are blindly calling `[0]` on it: `command = user_input[0]` You should move `if/else` check out of `for` loop.

Comment: OP explicitly said it would be a list.  Presumably he would add whatever sanity checks are appropriate when adapting this answer for his use.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!